# Default an EngineYard Jruby instance to 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, engineyard

I have a Rails app I am trying to test in Jruby on Engineyard. I can get it locally working when i switch ruby version in rvm to 1.9.2 (jruby) However when on engineyard a deploy fails:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':'
```

I solved this error locally using 1.9.2 `export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9` I have tried this on engineayrd but i am still getting the same error.

Does anyone know how to set EngineYard to default to 1.9.2 not ruby-1.8.7-p330?

Any help is greatly appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the following in /home/deploy/.jrubyrc:

```
compat.version=1.9
```

Comment: that file is not in that directory?

Comment: but thank you for the response, i have found trinidad_config, however adding the above line did not make a difference. unless the instance needs to be restarted for it to take effect?

Comment: Sorry, create the file and put that line in it.

Comment: Aha that worked. I'm now getting a SQL error but I'm getting there. Thanks for your help.